# Sending data and error from controller to view

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller, parameter-passing

I have a beginner problem please:

I know how to pass data to the view as below:

```
   $data['documents'] = $this->documents_model->get_documents();
   $data['main_content'] = 'document_view';
   $this->load->view('layout', $data);
```

I also know how to pass errors to the view as below:

```
   $this->load->view('upload_view', array('error' => ''));
```

But how can I pass both data and error to the view? I tried placing the error into $data-key as below, but that gives me the word 'array' in the view which I don't want.

```
   $data['error'] = array('error' => '');
```

I also tried sending $error and $data in the load->view (as 2 params seperated by comma) which gives me syntax error. And now I ran out of my limited ideas so I thought I ask here.

Thank you very much for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$data['error'] = "Your message here";
```

Now, in the view just echo the message like this:

```
<?=(isset($error))?$error:''?>
```

Comment: its the isset I see. Thank you!